# SQL query to find number of successes between failures

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have an oracle database table that contains test result records.  Each record contains the test START_TIME, the INSTRUMENT that the test was performed on, and an ERROR_CODE if an error occurred during the test, among other information.

For every record with an ERROR_CODE equal to '5900', '6900' or '5905', I need to determine the number of successful tests (ERROR_CODE = null) that have occurred on that INSTRUMENT before the datetime of the error record.  In other words, I need to know the number of successful tests performed on the instrument before an error was generated.

The database contains over 500 instruments that can each have between 1 and 500,000 test records.

Notes: Only interested in number of successes before ERROR_CODES '5900', '6000' and '5905'. Some instruments may have zero of those errors.  Some instruments may have multiple consecutive errors, with no success between them. An error may have occurred on that instrument's first or last test.

Example:

```
START_TIME          INSTRUMENT  ERROR_CODE
12/1/2015 22:15:03  A540        null
12/1/2015 22:17:14  A700        null
12/1/2015 22:17:53  A700        null
12/1/2015 22:19:24  A700        5905
12/1/2015 23:28:15  A700        null
12/1/2015 23:35:10  A540        6000
12/2/2015 02:15:13  A540        5900
12/2/2015 03:07:03  A540        null
12/2/2015 03:44:52  A540        null
12/2/2015 09:15:56  A700        null
12/2/2015 14:17:09  A700        5900
12/2/2015 17:15:42  A980        null
12/3/2015 08:17:53  A540        5900
12/3/2015 08:18:49  A540        5900
12/3/2015 11:17:57  A540        null
```

should give the following results

```
ERROR_TIME          INSTRUMENT  SUCCESSES_BEFORE_ERROR
12/1/2015 22:19:24  A700        2
12/1/2015 23:35:10  A540        1
12/2/2015 02:15:13  A540        1
12/2/2015 14:17:09  A700        4
12/3/2015 08:17:53  A540        3
12/3/2015 08:18:49  A540        3
```

Comment: How do you know when the test period has started/ended? In your example input data, how do you know that the row for A540 at 12/1/2015 22:15:03 is in the same test period as the row at 12/3/2015 08:18:49? Also, what happens if there's a row with an error number you're not interested in? Does that count as a success, does it get filtered out from the resultset before we start calculating things, or something else?

Comment: Each individual record is a complete test period (one test).  If there is an error code on that record then the test was unsuccessful.  For each unsuccessful test (with ERROR_CODE '5900', '6000', or '5905') I want to know the number of successful tests that occurred before it on that instrument.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to get your data (sorted by `INSTRUMENT`) into a cursor and loop through it. You may be able to phrase a SELECT with CASEs, but it would be extremely complex, and I don't think will display significant performance improvement.

Comment: So, you are looking for a cumulative count, where an error on an instrument does not restart the count at 0? So, the successful test from the first row in your sample data is counted as a "success" for that instrument for all future counts? The data suggests so, just making sure.

Comment: Correct, a success should not restart the count

Comment: Do you mean, an ERROR should not restart the count? That's what I was asking. Row #4 is an error for instrument 7000. That did NOT restart the count of successes; the two successes for that instrument, before that error, are counted again for later errors. Is that your business case? (Usually an error RESTARTS the count of successes, but that is not what you show.)

Comment: Sorry, yes I meant an ERROR does not restart the count. But if it makes a big difference in terms of performance or complexity of the query then either way is fine because I can probably correct for it afterward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way using analytic functions:

```
WITH test_results AS (SELECT to_date('12/01/2015 22:15:03', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_time, 'A540' instrument, NULL ERROR_CODE FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT to_date('12/01/2015 22:17:14', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_time, 'A700' instrument, NULL ERROR_CODE FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT to_date('12/01/2015 22:17:53', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_time, 'A700' instrument, NULL ERROR_CODE FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT to_date('12/01/2015 22:19:24', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_time, 'A700' instrument, 5905 ERROR_CODE FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT to_date('12/01/2015 23:28:15', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_time, 'A700' instrument, NULL ERROR_CODE FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT to_date('12/01/2015 23:35:10', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_time, 'A540' instrument, 6000 ERROR_CODE FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT to_date('12/02/2015 02:15:13', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_time, 'A540' instrument, 5900 ERROR_CODE FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT to_date('12/02/2015 03:07:03', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_time, 'A540' instrument, NULL ERROR_CODE FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT to_date('12/02/2015 03:44:52', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_time, 'A540' instrument, NULL ERROR_CODE FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT to_date('12/02/2015 09:15:56', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_time, 'A700' instrument, NULL ERROR_CODE FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT to_date('12/02/2015 14:17:09', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_time, 'A700' instrument, 5900 ERROR_CODE FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT to_date('12/02/2015 17:15:42', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_time, 'A980' instrument, NULL ERROR_CODE FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT to_date('12/03/2015 08:17:53', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_time, 'A540' instrument, 5900 ERROR_CODE FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT to_date('12/03/2015 08:18:49', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_time, 'A540' instrument, 5900 ERROR_CODE FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT to_date('12/03/2015 11:17:57', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_time, 'A540' instrument, NULL ERROR_CODE FROM dual)
-- end of mimicking a table with data in it called "test_results"
-- for use in the following select statement:
SELECT start_time,
       instrument,
       running_total success_before_error
FROM   (SELECT start_time,
               instrument,
               ERROR_CODE,
               sum(CASE WHEN ERROR_CODE IS NOT NULL THEN 0
                        ELSE 1
                   END) OVER (PARTITION BY instrument ORDER BY start_time) running_total
        FROM   test_results)
WHERE  ERROR_CODE IS NOT NULL -- this may need to be "error_code in (5900, 6000, 5905)"
ORDER BY start_time;

START_TIME          INSTRUMENT SUCCESS_BEFORE_ERROR
------------------- ---------- --------------------
12/01/2015 22:19:24 A700                          2
12/01/2015 23:35:10 A540                          1
12/02/2015 02:15:13 A540                          1
12/02/2015 14:17:09 A700                          4
12/03/2015 08:17:53 A540                          3
12/03/2015 08:18:49 A540                          3
```

Comment: or  simply use `count(case when error_code is null then 1 end)  over...`

Answer (score 0):

There may be a way to do this with analytic functions (no doubt there is).  But the simplest way to express the logic -- in my opinion -- is to use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from t t2
        where t2.instrument = t.instrument and
              t2.start_time < t.start_time and
              t2.error_code is null
       ) as SUCCESSES_BEFORE_ERROR
from t
where t.error_code is not null;
```

Comment: Shouldn't the final where condition be `t.error_code is not null`?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know source table name I call it `table_one`.

**EDIT:** As I see now I make a mistake I calculate cosequece of successfull test. I leave it as is

```
ordered_tab as ( 
select  START_TIME           
       ,INSTRUMENT 
       ,ERROR_CODE 
       ,row_number() over (partition by INSTRUMENT order by START_TIME) rn 
  from table_one) 
 select START_TIME  as ERROR_TIME      
       ,INSTRUMENT 
       ,SUCCESSES_BEFORE_ERROR
   FROM ( 
     select START_TIME           
           ,INSTRUMENT 
           ,ERROR_CODE 
           ,rn -1 
           - nvl(last_value(nvl2(ERROR_CODE,rn,null) ignore nulls) 
             over (partition by INSTRUMENT order by START_TIME rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding),0) as SUCCESSES_BEFORE_ERROR
      from ordered_tab 
  ) where ERROR_CODE IN (5905, 5900, 6000)
```